# Whats wrong in this code? Firebase Rule

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I just started work on Firebase and copied and pasted code from their site to test it, but it isn't working.

[image]

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? what error did you receive?

Comment: You should be more specific, with this information nobody can help you

Comment: You should try to delete the 2nd line and write it again(Don't paste) .. maybe it has mapped some wrong character ..

Comment: When I copy/paste the rules into my own console they save without problems. So am inclined to agree with @shadygoneinsane that it may be an invalid non-printable character in the original copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, it's version 2 now. I tried this but it still didn't work for me.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
```

Then I reinstalled my firebase. This happened because of

```
sudo npm i -g firebase-tools
```

Instead, make sure to remove sudo.

```
npm i -g firebase-tools
```

Comment: What you want exactly for this firebase rules, can u explain bit more?